# Why do we need str(f.read()) when reading a file in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, file

```
def get_story_string():
    f = open("story.txt", "r")
    story = str(f.read())
    f.close()
    return story
```

I don't understand why one uses str() here. This function works well if I remove str() as well, i.e.

```
story = f.read()
```

Is `str()` redundant in this function? This function was written by a MIT student.
According to [Methods of File Objects](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html)
To read a file’s contents, call `f.read(size)`, which reads some quantity of data and returns it *as a string*. size is an optional numeric argument.

Comment: yes, it is redundant.

Comment: I believe you answered your own question when you said `This function works well if I remove str()`

Comment: @TimCastelijns: finding out that something *sometimes* works by omitting a code fragment does not provide any guarantees that part is useless... Take for instance locks: a lot of programs will work in 99% of the cases without proper locking...

Comment: And now you're quoting the docs that also tell you it's redundant. What's left to know?

Answer (score 1):

Per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects), a file object's `read` method will return a string when the file is opened in text mode, or a bytes object in binary mode.